# How can I play Halo 4 offline Split screen VS.?

Tags: xbox-360, halo-4

I want to play Halo 4 offline with friends. We want to play against each other. Anyone knows how to play offline split screen vs?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine it being different from 3? Can't be that hard to find it can it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the menu, you can go to :

**War Games** > **Custom Game**

Then you can set your options for the custom game you want.

This is for **Player vs Player** only though. No bots.